# Getting error while trying to use a list with numpy to get some stat values

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

Hi I am having problems with this code:

```
**import numpy as np
# Summarize the data about minutes spent in the classroom
#total_minutes = total_minutes_by_account.values()
total_minutes = list(total_minutes_by_account.values())
type(total_minutes)
# Printing out the samething converting to a list
print('Printing out the samething converting to a list ')
print(type(total_minutes))
print ('Mean:', np.mean(total_minutes))
print ('Standard deviation:', np.std(total_minutes))
print ('Minimum:', np.min(total_minutes))
print ('Maximum:', np.max(total_minutes))**
```

The error I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-945375bf6098> in <module>()
      3 # Summarize the data about minutes spent in the classroom
      4 #total_minutes = total_minutes_by_account.values()
----> 5 total_minutes = list(total_minutes_by_account.values())
      6 type(total_minutes)
      7 #print(total_minutes)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I really would lie to know how I can make this work, I can do it with pandas converitng it to a numpy array and the getting values for the statistics I want with numpy

Comment: How about `total_minutes = list(total_minutes_by_account)` since it is already a list?

Comment: Thank you @StephenRauch I did not see that :)